# Destructor immediately calls and deletes my arrays

Tags: c++, matrix, destructor

I am working on a Matrix class for a CS project, and I'm trying to work on the constructors. The project calls for two different constructors, one just calling out the numbers of rows and columns and making them all 0 and another using an initializer list to assign the values. The header file so far is:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>> i_list;

class Matrix {
public:
double ** arr;
uint mainRows;
uint mainCols;

Matrix(uint rows, uint cols);
Matrix(const i_list & list);
Matrix(const Matrix & m);
~Matrix();

};
```

Some of the test cases require you to both define the rows and use the initializer list, for example:

```
Matrix d(2,2);
d = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

But I noticed that every time I try and run this kind of code, the destructor will immediately delete the double ** arr which is where the values for the Matrix's are stored. Here is the code for the constructors:

```
    Matrix::Matrix(uint rows, uint cols)
{
    mainRows = rows;
    mainCols = cols;
    arr = new double*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < mainRows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new double[cols];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < mainRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mainCols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const i_list & list)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    mainRows = list.size();
    mainCols = (*list.begin()).size();
    arr = new double*[mainRows];
    for (std::initializer_list<double> I : list) {
        j = 0;
        arr[i] = new double[mainCols];
        for (double d : I) {
            arr[i][j] = d;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix & m)
{
    this->arr = m.arr;
    this->mainRows = m.mainRows;
    this->mainCols = m.mainCols;
    for (uint i = 0; i < mainRows; i++) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < mainCols; j++) {
            this->arr[i][j] = m.arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < mainRows; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr; 
}
```

I guess since its calling a constructor for the same object twice it's creating two double ** ars and that's why the Destructor want's to delete the original, but then I can't call on the values for other functions. Can somebody help me out with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you overload the `operator=`?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. I also recommend you take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And of course read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) if you did not.

Comment: Read up on rule of three

Comment: I didn't think about that, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your copy-constructor only copies the *pointer* of the source object, not allocates new memory.

This is problematic because

```
d = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

creates a temporary object out of `{{1,2},{3,4}}`. You statement is actually equal to

```
d = Matrix({{1,2},{3,4}});
```

which is equal to

```
d.operator=(Matrix({{1,2},{3,4}}));
```

After the assignment is made, you have two objects pointing to the same memory for `arr`. And then the temporary object is destructed, leading to `arr` inside `d` to become invalid, as it no longer points to allocated memory.

The naive solution is simple: Allocate memory for `arr` to point to in the copy-constructor. The *better* solution is to stop using pointers and dynamic allocation, and instead use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and live by [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero), where you don't need any copy-constructor, no copy-assignment operator and no destructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix & m)
{
    this->arr = m.arr;
    this->mainRows = m.mainRows;
    this->mainCols = m.mainCols;
    for (uint i = 0; i < mainRows; i++) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < mainCols; j++) {
            this->arr[i][j] = m.arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Note yuo do not creating actual copy here. `this->arr = m.arr;` makes both pointers to pointing same part of memory so new and old instance of `Matrix` are sharing this memory. So flowing `for` loops does nothing.

Than when one of instances is destroyed the other instance is pointing to memory which is freed.